# how to learn objectArx?

Tags: autocad, objectarx

i have intermediate c++ knowledge and i was write some c# tools to autocad now i want to learn ObjectArx

i spent some time to google for tutorial or something start with and get that link http://arxdummies.blogspot.com/

this is only useful link on the net unfortunately the blog writen in 2005 and we are in 2011 and there are autocad 2012 and visual studio 2010 it's big difference

any one now recent tutorial or free book to start with it

Thank you